# Cmake error variables set to NOTFOUND for HDF5 library as it has already been linked?

Tags: python, caffe, archlinux

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY
    linked by target "caffe" in directory /tmp/yaourt-tmp-user/aur-caffe/src/caffe-rc3/src/caffe
```

I have uninstalled HDF5 forcefully and reinstalled it via yaourt again, but hdf5 still links to the target, how do I fix this?